# MERN ECommerce database enquire

Tags: mongodb, backend, mern, web-hosting, strapi

I am currently making an ECommerce website for a local business as part of my portfolio and I have the front-end and back-end working but I am starting to wonder how I am going to store the product's images with the rest of the product's data (name, category, sizes, reviews etc ) in my database, so I can fetch it in the frontend without having to manually save the images in a image folder.

after doing some research, I don't think mongodb would be good enough for this. I found Strapi which looks like a good choice but I am not sure what would be the best practice for this. also, in the best case scenario the business uses the website, how would they be able to add, remove, and edit products displayed on the website without me having to constantly manually edit the website? eg if they want to do a discount on a product. is there an API I could implement into my code to make someone who doesn't code be able to add, edit or remove products or am I going to be an unpaid programmer for them for the foreseeable future

Any help would be appreciated and any suggestions for database alternatives or maybe hosting a website for free would really help, thanks